# Как показать отмеченные checkbox при скрытии списка?

Tags: html, css, jquery, checkbox

помогите решить проблему, есть выпадающий список с чекбоксами, изначально список скрыт, при нажатии на "Категории", чекбоксы появляются. Цель сделать так, чтобы выбранные чекбоксы оставались видимыми, после скрытия списка и возвращались на свое место после повторного открытия списка.
https://08sip.csb.app/

Comment: Local Storage, Cookies, Sessions, DB, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Применяйте `display:none` не списку, а элементам списка, которые не содержат отмеченных `input`

```js
// вариант 1
            /*$('.publications-select__header').click(function() {
                $('.publications-select__list-collapsed input:checkbox:not(:checked)')
                    .parent('.publications-select__item')
                    .toggle('slow');
            });*/
            
            // вариант 2
            $('.publications-select__header').click(function() {
                $('.publications-select__list-collapsed input:checkbox:not(:checked)')
                    .parent('.publications-select__item')
                    .animate({
                        height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
                     });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
              <!--publications-->
              <div class="container-publications container">
                <div class="publications">
                  <h2 class="publications-header section-header">Издания</h2>
                  <div class="publications-select">
                    <h3 class="publications-select__header">Категории</h3>
                    <ul class="publications-select__list-collapsed active">
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="bestsellers" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="bestsellers" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Бестселлеры</label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="art" class="publications-select__input"><label for="art" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Искусство</label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="architecture" class="publications-select__input"><label for="architecture" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Архитектура</label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="design" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="design" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Дизайн
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="fashion" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="fashion" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Мода
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="for-children" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="for-children" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Детям
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="fiction" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="fiction" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Художественная литература
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="journalism" class="publications-select__input"><label for="journalism" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Публицистика
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="travel-guides" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="travel-guides" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Путеводители
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="philosophy" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="philosophy" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Философия
                        </label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="educational-literature" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="educational-literature" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Учебная
                          литература</label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="publications-select__item">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="newspapers" class="publications-select__input">
                        <label for="newspapers" class="publications-select__label" data-checked="false">
                          <span class="publications-select__span_box"></span>Журналы и
                          газеты</label>
                        <span class="publications-select__span_close"></span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="publications-select__warehouse"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Можно вырубить через display none, но дело в том, как сё это аннимировать

Comment: например jquery animate

Comment: Как это сделать с выборкой элементов?

Comment: изучайте на примере

Comment: Sanya H, спасибо за помощь, доработал на основании animate(), теперь все работает как надо

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallery-08sip?file=/main.js